# highcharts non numeric range on secondary yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

As seen in the right yAxis: 0, LOW, MED, HIGH - those are non numerical and I was wondering if it is possible to label it like that? I would assume I need to assign numerical values to each one, behind the scenes, otherwise highcharts won't know what is what.

I am new to highcharts, so I was not successful when searching for that option in the api. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use labels formatter and produce names as you need.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Thanks, I was able to add those to the right yAxis, now I am trying to set the LOW tick line to the 15 line for 15, MED between 30 and 45, and HIGH to 60 http://jsfiddle.net/bkmorse/QKjNz/4/

Comment: I am not really sure, pretty new to highcharts. Just looking to make sure 60 minutes ties into HIGH, and so on.